# Static variable in Asynctask class with or against?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, performance, android-asynctask

I have an Asynctask class and a I have an array inside that class which is to be filled by the `doInBackground(Void...)` and then I am accessing that variable from other activities. My question is will the thread ever dies or finishes execution if I have a refrence to that class variable from other activities?
For example:

```
public class SendReport extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Boolean> {

static ArrayList data=new ArrayList<>();
 @Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
    sendReport();
    return null;
}

public void sendReport() {

    //Do something here to fill the Array
}
```

And then from the activity I am using the static variable:

```
SendReport.data.get(2);
```

Comment: So the send report is sending report to a remote server and you are waiting back for a response. Is that right? @yanozai

Comment: Yes I am doing that @SalvatoryBaya

Comment: And you want to use the values which the remote sever sends back as a response inside your application. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes indeed @SalvatoryBaya

Comment: Okay now i get it. First I would suggest to use a library to do this kind of API call. Library i suggest is like Retrofit with RxJava. But regardless, I would create a a response object, For instance, if response is user's information, the the response Object will be called User or something like that. And i will parse the response string onPostExecute and save the values on the Response object using Gson Library. This is one of the standard procedures in Handling API calls.

Comment: Yes I am  doing exactly that but in my case is JSONObjects which contains the user information. If change my app to use Retrofit i would have to rewrite 1000s lines of code since we are about to be done with the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe static variables are related to class not the object itself. If you read the array from anywhere it should not keep the thread running.

Having said that, you have to be really careful with what you are storing in the array. Because the array is static the objects in the array will be there as long as the jvm is running (This is unless they are explicitly removed from the array). I would strongly advice against doing whatever you are doing this way

Comment: Okay, what are your suggestion on storing the data that I retrieved from the server?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Can you elaborate more please? In question there is no word about server.

Comment: Okay, I am sending the report and then I am getting the response which contains data and I am parsing the data (Strings) to put inside the Array

Comment: Ho long do you need to keep the data for? Can you use a database?

Comment: I am keeping the data until the application closes. the data I am receiving is a lot. Do you think that I should use a database? The application we developed is about to be finished and saving the data into a database will require us to rewrite 1000 lines of code

Comment: The thing is if you have a lot of data you are keeping all of that in the memory which could affect your app performance and possibly memory leaks. Having a database maybe fixes the memory issue but adds more complexity and some overhead. I would suggest that you measure the memory performance of your app before doing anything. Also try to use some sort of LRUCache so that your memory does not grow over a cretain threshold.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the suggestions I will review the requirements and see if it fits to put the data in a database

Answer (score 0):

A thread, `t`, runs until;

- Its `run()` method returns, or
- Its `run()` method throws an exception, or
- Any thread calls `t.stop()` (**Bad Idea**), or
- Any thread calls `System.exit(...)` (not-so-great idea).

The fact that some other thread is able to access variables (e.g., your `data` variable) that may have been updated by thread `t` has no bearing on when or whether thread `t` will stop running.